# Rewriting subfolders to specific parent folder in Wordpress

Tags: htaccess, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

I have created one page with name /parent/ and assigned new template template-parent.php that has some 3rd party software showing via JavaScript. I need to rewrite all subfolders to this parent so when someone tries to access

domain.com/parent/something

the url will remain the same, but he will be pointed to domain.com/parent/ so that loaded scripts could process the request.

The code should be something like this

RewriteRule ^(parent)/(.+)$ /$1/ [QSA,L]

but I am not sure where to put it, should I use .htaccess or put it in functions.php
If in htaccess, then will it be before, after or in the middle of wordpress code.

Comment: That `RewriteRule` won't work regardless where it is placed in the `.htaccess` file, so you should instead use [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) - or there is [`add_rewrite_endpoint()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/), but if you want to target specific Pages only, then the former function is better. But what is that `something`; does it bring any specific meaning, or is it by "subfolders" you meant actual Pages that are children of the `parent`?

Comment: thank you, that did the trick